# Deleting files and folders

Tags: git

Just learning Git.

I wanted to remove folders and files from the repository that did not belong there.

1. I cloned the repository on my local machine:
   **git clone https://github.com/blah/blah.git**
2. I removed the files and folders my dragging them to trash. I'm pretty sure this is where I went wrong.
3. I edited one file that needed to be changed and kept.
4. The files I deleted show as deleted show as deleted in **git status**
5. Then, using **git gui,** I committed the file that I edited, then pushed - **git push**.

Now when I look git  at the master repository on Github, the folders and files I deleted are still there.

What is the proper procedure for deleting files and folders?

Once I cloned or pulled, should I have used **git rm {foldername}**?

Moving forward, how do I resolve this? For when I did a pull, its says its up to date. But my local doesn't have the the deleted folders but the master repo on Github still does.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn’t add or commit the deleted folders.

Answer (score 1):

You should also "commit" the deletion. I'm not using Git GUI but from the command line it's `$ git rm path/to/deleted/file`. There's also `$ git add -A` that would have done the job in your case.

From now, you need to make a new commit that deletes file.

Comment: Thanks @gregory. I need to get more comfortable with the command line.

So basically, when removing files/folders, we have to use a the git rm command. I just wanted to verify this. Thanks!

Comment: In Git GUI likely it's phrased as "staging" or "committing" deleted files. From your description, your commit only contains the edits to the file you wanted to keep. On the CLI you can see which files are changed by a commit by doing `$ git log --stat <commit hash>`

Comment: Yes. That's the step I missed in the Git Gui. I had assumed, that by NOT selecting the files that I deleted, Git would update the repository without the deleted files. 

Now I know that you have to include the deleted files in the commit so Git knows to delete them.  

So I went back and committed the deleted files, and pushed to the repository, and it worked! Now the Github repository is less the deleted files. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`git rm` only deletes a file, so to remove a whole folder/directory including its subdirectories you'll have to use the `git rm -f folder-name` command.

1. In the terminal, navigate to your local repository.
2. Ensure you are in the default branch: git checkout master.
3. The `rm -r` command will recursively remove your folder.

   ```
   git rm -r folder-name
   ```
4. Commit the change.

   ```
   git commit -m "Description"
   ```
5. Push the change to your remote repository.

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```